# Salesforce record History inconsistent

Tags: apex, issue

I have been puzzling with following issue in my Production where status of the record doesn't get changed but history tracking shows that it was changed. So basically it seems that something fishy is going on behind the scene. Now let me give you insight of the problem.

In our Salesforce, Apttus contract management managed package is installed along with echo-Sign app. Whenever Customer signs contract echo sign changes the agreement status to 'Fully Signed'.
Now we have a trigger which detects this and changes the status from 'Fully signed' to 'Activated'.

[image: Agreement History]

Now in this image you can see two entries.
1. echo integration user activating agreement through trigger, however this is visible in history, but record was not 'Active'.
2. So user manually 'Activated' agreement.

There is no trace of how record was reverted from 'Activated' to 'Fully Signed'.
I feel there is something fishy.

And yes just to be clear that this happens for random agreements, not for all.

we have Apttus Contract Management version:8.368

Thanks,
Bhupendra